# Ошибка с сертификатом 102

Tags: linux, sql-server, ssl, virtualbox, zabbix

Столкнулся с проблемой, при создании нового элемента в Zabbix 6.0 появляется эта ошибка: `Cannot connect to ODBC DSN: [SQL_ERROR]:[08001][-1][[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate]|[08001][-1][[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection]`, мне нужно мониторить данные таблицы в бд раз в час, и создать триггер.

Comment: Ээээ, ты в качеств БД для хранения всякого заббиксоного mssql что ли юзануть решил?